# Devise Validations with Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, polymorphism

I have a User model generated using Devise. This User model has 2 types (Buyer or Seller) created using Polymorphic Associations.

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :user, as: :owner, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
validates_presence_of :user
validates_associated :user


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

after_commit :transaction_success
after_rollback :transaction_failed

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

validates :email, presence: true
validates :first_name, presence: true

private
  def transaction_success
    logger.info "Transfer succeed for Account #{self.to_param}"
  end

  def transaction_failed
    logger.warn "Transfer failed for Account #{self.to_param}"
  end
```

end
When an User is Registered, he does it from an specific registration link (/buyer/new or /seller/new), calling the create method from the controller:

```
 def create
@buyer = Buyer.new(buyer_params)
@user = User.new(user_params)
respond_to do |format|
  begin
    User.transaction do 
      @buyer.save
      @user.owner_id = @buyer.id
      @user.owner_type = "Buyer"
      @user.save
    end
  format.html { sign_in_and_redirect @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
  format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

The problem is that sometimes the transaction fails but saves a Buyer without an User. Also, the Devise validations, or any validation that I include in the User Model doesn't make any difference, allowing users to be created without any email, password etc.

How can I fix the transaction and make sure that the validations work??